# jQuery add to data-filter without replacing existing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie to jQuery.

I'm trying to add more data to data-filter dynamically. This is currently replacing em1 with em2. How do a I get it to add em2 to the data-filter without replacing em1?

HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-filter='em1'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='em2'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='em3'>stuff</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').attr('data-filter', 'newEm');
```

What I'm getting is:

HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-filter='newEm'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='newEm'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='newEM'>stuff</a>
```

Result I want is:

HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-filter='em1 newEm'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='em2 newEm'>stuff</a>
<a href='#' data-filter='em3 newEM'>stuff</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate it.

Loop through each element, and concatenate the old value plus the new value.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-filter', $(this).attr('data-filter') + ' newEm');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Thats not working as I need it though. I'll edit my question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-filter", $(this).attr("data-filter") + " newEm");
});
```